# Ghostscript 9.06 error

Tags: php, pdf, ghostscript

I've upgraded Ghostscript from version 9.02 to version 9.06 and I get an error regarding fonts:

```
> Can't find (or can't open) font file /usr/share/ghostscript/9.06/Resource/Font/NimbusSanL-Regu.
> Can't find (or can't open) font file NimbusSanL-Regu. 
> Can't find (or can't open) font file /usr/share/ghostscript/9.06/Resource/Font/NimbusSanL-Regu. 
> Can't find (or can't open) font file NimbusSanL-Regu. 
> Querying operating system for font files... 
> Loading NimbusSanL-Regu font from /usr/share/fonts/default/Type1/n019003l.pfb... 4136044 2757274 2600856 1287906 3 done.
```

Here is the code I use to downsize a PDF file:

```
system("/usr/local/bin/gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -dPDFSETTINGS=/screen -dColorImageDownsampleType=/Bicubic -dColorImageResolution=72 -dGrayImageDownsampleType=/Bicubic -dGrayImageResolution=72 -dMonoImageDownsampleType=/Bicubic -dMonoImageResolution=72 -sOutputFile=output2.pdf _document.pdf");
```

The PDF file is not the problem because I can downsize it with version 9.02 but I can't with version 9.06. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Where did you get Ghostscript from ? The error says that GS is unable to find the basic font set, and these are normally built into the executable using a ROM file system. This error suggests that your build is *not* using the ROM file system and is therefore a non-standard build. To fix this you need to find out where the fonts are stored, and use the -I switch to Include this directory in the font search path.

Comment: @KenS I got back to my hosting provider quoting your comment and now I get no font missing error. I still have one file that cannot be converted (the pages in the pdf are all black). I noticed this message when I try convertingg this file `code` Loading NimbusSanL-Regu font from /usr/share/ghostscript/9.06/Resource/Font/NimbusSanL-Regu... 4093308 2650326 2398416 1084890 3 done `code`

Comment: That line is simply Ghostscript telling you that its loading a font, it has to load fonts before it can use them. I would strongly suggest that you get a local copy of Ghostscript to try this out on rather than relying on a host. I can't possibly comment on the file with problems without seeing the file.